# C++ directory listing acting weird

Tags: c++

So I'm making a CMD implementation on Linux, but I ran into some problem.
If I change the working directory using the CD command like this:
    /$CD home
Then if I run the ls command without anything
    /home$ls
It lists nothing unless I execute this:
cd ./
or this:
ls ./
and it works again.
main.cpp:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "commands.h"
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
 string arr[4];
string out[4];
string dir("/");
void sep(string line)
{
 int i = 0;
 stringstream ssin(line);
 while (ssin.good() && i < 4){
 ssin >> arr[i];
 ++i;
 }
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
 out[i]=arr[i];
 }

}


int main()
{
//startup text
 string input;
 cout << "Linux\n" << system("uname -r") <<"\n";
 while (true) {
 cout << std::filesystem::current_path();
 getline (cin,input);
sep(input);
 if (input=="ver")
 {
 ver();
}
//exit
 else if (out[0]=="exit")
 {
 return 0;
 }
 else if (input=="")
 {
 }
 //echo
 else if (out[0]=="echo")
 {
 cout << out[1] << "\n";
 }
 else if (out[0]=="ls"||out[0]=="dir")
 {
 if (out[1]==""){
 list_dir(std::filesystem::current_path());

 }
 else
 list_dir(out[1]);

 }
 else if (out[0]=="clear")
 {
 printf("\033[2J");
 printf("\033[H");

 }
 else if (out[0]=="exec")
 {
 string name=out[1];
 const char *namecc=name.c_str();
 open(namecc);
 }
 else if (out[0]=="cd")
 {

 const char *chd=out[1].c_str();
 cout << chd << "\n";

 chdir(chd);
 if (chdir(chd)==-1)
 {
 cout << "chdir() Returned -1,directory not exist or error\n";

 }

 }
 else cout << "Bad command or file name\n";


}

}
```

command.h:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <filesystem>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
 #include <dirent.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 using namespace std;
 using namespace boost::filesystem;
 namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 void ver()
 {
 std::cout << "CMD for linux 1.0\n";
 }

 int list_dir(string ddddd) {
 DIR *d;

 struct dirent *dir;
 const char* p=ddddd.c_str();
 d = opendir(p);

 if (d)

 {

 while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)

 {

 printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);

 }

 closedir(d);

 }

 return 0;
 }


 int cd(string aa)
 {
 const char *bbbbb=aa.c_str();
 DIR* a=opendir(bbbbb);
 if (a)
 {
 return 0;
 }
 else return 1;
 }
 int open(const char* file)
 {
 FILE *handle = popen(file, "r");

 if (handle == NULL) {
 return 1;
 }

 char buf[64];
 size_t readn;
 while ((readn = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), handle)) > 0) {
 fwrite(buf, 1, readn, stdout);
 }

 pclose(handle);

 return 0;
 }
```

btw I'm still not really good at c++ yet so if the code is unoptimized please give some suggestions about how can I make it better,thanks.

Comment: These snippets seem taken almost at random and are missing important context. Additionally, please take a short moment to delete things like completely blank lines that only serve to make your code longer and harder to absorb without scrolling. You should also make an effort to indent this consistently as right now it's all over the place and the structure is far from clear.

Comment: Why are you calling `chdir` twice? Call it once and test the result. If it does error, check `errno`.

Comment: You're dumping far too much code here. Please provide a [mcve] (with emphasis on **minimal**) that demonstrates the issue, instead of dumping your entire source. We shouldn't have to wade through a swamp of unrelated code to try to figure out your issue.Also read [ask], because your problem description is rather unclear.

Comment: [mcve] <- good advice